# Deserialise JSON String in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I received NSData object `data` from REST API. That contains JSON data which I want to parse.

```
 {   
    JsonResult = "[{
                   \"IsAuth\":\"true\",
                   \"User\":\"
                   [
                     {
                      \\\"userid\\\":\\\"josephH\\\",
                      \\\"firstname\\\":\\\"joseph\\\",
                      \\\"lastname\\\":\\\"Henry\\\",
                      }
                   ]\"}]"
 }
```

This statement gave me the result as a String like below which I am not able to parse as JSON.
`myData = [data valueForKey:@"JsonResult"];`

```
                   "[{
                       \"IsAuth\":\"true\",
                       \"User\":\"
                       [
                         {
                          \\\"userid\\\":\\\"josephH\\\",
                          \\\"firstname\\\":\\\"joseph\\\",
                          \\\"lastname\\\":\\\"Henry\\\",
                          }
                       ]\"}]"
```

When I try to pass this `mydata` to `JSONSerialization` the code crashes.

How do I cast the above string to NSDictionary so that I can parse them and use the values of IsAuth and User.?

Code:

```
    [LDService authenticateUser:Uname.text passwordString:Password.text completeBlock:^(NSData * data){

        NSError *error;
        NSData *jsonData;
        NSString *jsonString = nil;
        NSMutableDictionary *jsonDict;
        if([NSJSONSerialization isValidJSONObject:data])
        {
            jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:data
                                                               options:kNilOptions
                                                                 error:&error];
            jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        }
        NSString *formattedString = [jsonString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\\"" withString:@"'"];
        NSLog(@"Formatted string %@",formattedString);
        [jsonDict setObject:formattedString forKey:@"JsonResult"];
        NSLog(@"Parsed json %@",jsonDict);

    }];
```

Comment: Your response JsonResult is string not a proper JSON.

Comment: You can check your JSON not valid format: http://jsonviewer.stack.hu

Comment: Actually, I have serialised the json multiple times. So JsonResult is a string but it contains data which is like JSON. I have shortened the JSON result but originally it is a long JSON which contains JSON inside a string. I have to deserialise the data multiple times but i am failing to do so.

Comment: Do you mean you have to deserialize every single value inside the key?

Comment: Yes, so that I can use the value. But I am not able to parse the string I have obtained.

Comment: @AyushOjha: First convert this data into string & then replace occurrence of `@"\\\"` using `[string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\\"" withString:@"'"]`

Comment: Ask the operator of the Rest API to send better (valid) JSON. The mistake lies clearly there.

Comment: There were some constraints in sending that valid JSON, thats why this way has been opted.

Answer (score 1):

Pass your data as `data`

```
NSError *error;
NSString *jsonString = nil;
if([NSJSONSerialization isValidJSONObject:data])
{
    NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:data
                                                       options:kNilOptions
                                                         error:&error];
    jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}
```

then replace occurance of `@"\\\"` with `@"'"`

```
NSString *formattedString = [jsonString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\\"" withString:@"'"];
```

then use this formattedString.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131887/discussion-on-answer-by-iyoung-deserialise-json-string-in-objective-c).

Answer (score 0):

I have investigates your json file from [Json formatter & Validator](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/), there are lots of error in your json file, so first check your file from this validator and this formatter gives you error with description. Re-build your json file, if you still getting any problem then ask.

Comment: There is no problem in the string, Since it is purely not JSON string, but it can be parse. I did it in swift. and I could access the value of IsAuth. I am not able to do that in objective C.